# Unable to install Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I had a Windows XP. I also had JDK6. I downloaded "Android installer r11" for windows. When I click the installer, the error message is displayed as alert Java SE development kit is not found, Then the installation cannot happen.

But in my system I had a Java SE 6. I cannot find why it is not take the Java.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16176 click 'back' and then 'next' should solve the problem.

Comment: I also click back and click next.Then also same problem arrise suresh manchi

Comment: Now i click back and click next.It works .After that sdk manager start then there is error alert message displayed like that "java petha not found".Tell me the solution to solve it

Comment: Back and next works for me too! Thanx! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%JAVA_HOME%` should be in your path. Half of the time you can have an SDK and be missing that variable.

Get thee to a command line and type `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, or simply see if you get any output from `javac -version`. The exact variable for Java home is probably not quite right, but the second step should work. If javac fails you, you either never installed  Java SDK (aka JDK) and instead got the SE, or you still haven't set the java binary folder into your path. **Use your Windows search and look for javac.exe.**

If nothing else works, go to java.sun.com and re-download and **install** a new SDK. The annoying part is that Glassfish and other things tend to complicate the java setup because they too must be set up during install or shortly thereafter.

Comment: WHEN I TYPE echo %JAVA_HOME% IN COMMAND PROMPT.THE FOLLWING OUTPUT COMES "E:\JAVA_6_EE_INSTALL\glassfishv3\jdk" BUT STILL THE SAME PROBLEM ARRISE WHEN I TRY TO INSTALL ANDROID

Comment: CAN YOU **PLEASE** STOP IT WITH THE CAPSLOCK?

Answer (score 4):

Try this step it may help you:
Installation sequence: JDK, Eclipse, ADT, Android SDK

#### 1. JDK

First, head over to [Oracle Web site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to download and install the latest Java Development Kit.

Ensure that the environment variables look something like this:

CLASSPATH

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib\tools.jar; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib\dt.jar;`

PATH:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin;`

At the command prompt type `java-version` to view the current system has been installed Java version.

---

#### 2. Eclipse IDE

Next, from the [Eclipse Web site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) Download the latest Java Eclipse Classic as our development environment, select here eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-win32 version, download the Eclipse is not good need to install, unzip to the right place to use.

---

#### 3.  ADT (Android Development Tools plugin, Android Development Kit)

ADT is an Eclipse plug-in, due to the use of the Eclipse version, the installation process referred to in the following menus and options may vary.

1. Then, start Eclipse, choose Help-> Install New Software ..., pop-up "Install" dialog box.
2. Click the Add ... button, pop-up "Add Site" dialog box:
3. Enter the Android update site here: Location: `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`/ When you're finished, click "OK", back to "Install" dialog box.
4. In the "Install" dialog box, select just added the update site, waiting to find the appropriate version of Eclipse Select ... "Develpoer Tools" of all items, all the way to click "Next", accept the agreement, click "Install" start the installation.
5. After the installation is complete, restart Eclipse.

#### 4. Android SDK

Next, from the [Google website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) download the latest android-sdk. Extract the zip file to appropriate directory, remember the absolute path. Run the SDK Manager installation.

In Eclipse, select `Windows` -> `Preference` -> `Android`, enter the directory on the step down the path, click "OK".

The latest SDK, only tools, but no longer contains the platform or the Google add-on, we need to use the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" to install and update, such as platforms, tools, add-ons, and documentation of these SDK components.

Comment: +1. This is way more helpful than I was, and we now know that OP has Java EE but is missing Eclipse and who knows what else. I think he's only downloaded the emulator.